# Check for error in command passed to popen API in cpp

Tags: c++, c, popen, compression

There is a cpp application where I want to read following type of compressed file-

1. file_name.gz
2. file_name.Z
3. file_name.tar.gz

For this purpose, I check the file extension and choose decompression technique accordingly. E.g. file_name.gz will be decompressed using "gunzip -C file_name.gz".

I want to get the FILE handle for decompressed file. I use popen() API for it. Now, there might be a case where gunzip/uncompress/tar fails while decompressing the file due to memory issues. How do I capture the failure in my CPP application. There is way to check if popen failed or not. What about command passed to popen().

Please help. I tried to find it at various places but could not get satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1):

When a process terminates normally, it is expected to return the exit code of 0 (legally, `EXIT_SUCCESS`) to the parent. Otherwise, in the case of a crash or any other abnormal termination, a non-zero value is expected to be returned. You can obtain the exit code by calling `pclose()`. If the code is 0, the child process most probably terminated successfully.

Comment: pclose() will close the file stream as well. How would I check it without closing the stream. If everything went well, I will still be closing the stream to check for any failure.

Comment: Just keep reading from the stream until the EOF. Then call pclose.

Comment: I used pclose() as suggested. But I am getting errno = ECHILD  for some of the cases. Can you please suggest what could be wrong here.

Comment: That's exactly the sign of a crash. See https://linux.die.net/man/3/pclose